# React-Native: different errors of project init (Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod...)

Tags: node.js, react-native

I can't make React-Native project. React throw different errors of type "no Such File or Directory". React-Native for Linux, and Android App building.

I install Recat-Native as in the guide on the official site. Next, I use the command

```
npx react-native init testProject
```

Then I get errors

For example:

```
✔ Downloading template
⠋ Copying template/home/pavel/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:265
        if (!chownErOk(er)) throw er
                            ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/pavel/projects/REACT_NATIVE_PROJECTS/CALC/calculator/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.chmodSync (node:fs:2007:3)
    at Object.chmodSync (/home/pavel/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:263:21)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/pavel/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/copyFiles.js:83:19)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:132:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'chmod',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/pavel/projects/REACT_NATIVE_PROJECTS/CALC/calculator/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
}

Node.js v20.5.0
```

How to fix this problem?

I reinstall node, reinstall npm, erase .npm user folder and install node from brew but React anyway throws an error. This error is about different files in the project.
Sometimes errors say about another file.

Comment: Sorry, in logs project name is "calculator"

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved the issue by downgrading my Node version from 18.x to 16.x. I think latest React Native version (0.72) has some issues with Node versions 18.x or higher. My current config is: Node: 16.20.2, NPM: 8.19.4, Yarn: not installed, Ubuntu: 22.04.3

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38113#issuecomment-1613686793), the root cause may lie in versioning shenanigans (specifically, prior activities with React Native of a previous version somehow blocking the `init` of a new version).

The proposed way to solve it is to upgrade the React Native version of some existing project before running `init` again.

The way I solved it instead, though, is by running the `init` with a `sudo`, interrupting it with `CTRL+C`, and trying again normally:

```bash
sudo npx react-native@latest init ProjectName`

  Need to install the following packages:
  react-native@0.72.4
  Ok to proceed? (y) 

// CTRL+C

npx react-native@latest init ProjectName
```

Voilà! I hope this works.